# Using Inheritance with AngularJS Components

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-components

I am using AngularJS components in anticipation of eventually moving to Angular2.  I have a component (Component1) that is essentially a dropdown with a few specific inputs and outputs.  I have another component (Component2) that is the exact same kind of dropdown, but has a dependency on the ng-model in Component1.  Is there a way to use inheritance in Component2 so that I do not have a bunch of duplicate code?

I can see how to use inheritance in Angular2, so this seems to be the best approach.  However, I can't find anything showing how to do this in Angular 1.5.

Component1 also requires a template, but it will be the same for both Component1 and Component2.  Also, Component2 will require an additional input for the value from Component1, as well as some code in the $onChanges event when that additional input changes.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best thing you can do is pass a model object to component 2 as bindings,

```
 app..component('component2', {
  bindings: {
    modelObject: '<'
  },
  controller: function () {
    //do stuff
  }
});
```

inside html

```
 <component2 model-object="$ctrl.modalObject"></component2>
```

when change occures in component1. if your component depends on that change
you need to use onchanges lifecycle hooks components.inside component2 controller

```
this.$onChanges=function(data){
   //this data has all changed values.. 
   // you can also use isFirstChange() to determine if it was the first or not.
    if(data.hasOwnProperty('modalObject'){
     if(!data.modalObject.isFirstChange()){//means its not the initialization}
}
}
```